# Angular @Input getter/setter and non-primitive values

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

**The Problem:** I want be able to call a function each time a property in the object the child component is bound to changes. However, the setter is only called once, even though the bound input property can visibly be seen updating.

This all came to be from the need to have a child component bind to its parent components property that happens to be a complex object with deeply nested properties. I've learned that the Angular onChange event does not fire when a nested property in an object changes. Hence the decision to use getters/setters instead. However, as seen by this question using getters/setters did not work either.  I've since changed my child component to subscribe to the same Observable that the parent component is subscribed to, thereby receiving the updates directly from the service and bypassing the parent component all together. I've done a lot of research on Angulars binding and TypeScript getters/setters and by all accounts it looks like my code show work, but it does not.

**Goal:** Understand why binding to a parent components property in a child component by using @Input with a getter/setter does not work as expected for non-primative types. Is there a fundamental concept I am missing or is there an implementation error in my code?

I will show some source code here and also attach a StackBlitz for anyone who wants to see it live in action.
[StackBlitz Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mlc-app-init-f79pew)

#### mock-data.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MockDataService {
  public updateSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public numObj = {
    'prop1': 'stuff',
    'prop2': 'stuff',
    'prop3': 'stuff',
    'prop4': 'stuff',
    'level1': {
      'level2': {
        'target': 0 //target is the prop that will be getting updated
      }
    }
  }
  constructor() {
    this.startDemo();
  }
  private startDemo(): void {
    //This is simulating the server sending updates
    //to the numObj
    setInterval(() => {
      this.numObj.level1.level2.target += 1;
      this.update();
    }, 4000);
  }
  private update(): void {
    try {
      this.updateSubject.next(this.numObj);
    } catch (err) {
      this.updateSubject.error(err);
    }
  }
}
```

#### app.component.ts (parent cmp)

**app.component.html**
`<child-cmp [targetNumber]="targetNumber"></child-cmp>`

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public targetNumber: any;
  public displayCurrentNumber: number;
  constructor(private mockDataService: MockDataService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.mockDataService.updateSubject.subscribe({
      next:(data) => this.onUpdate(data),
      error: (error) => alert(error),
    });
  }
  private onUpdate(data: any): void{
    if(data){
      this.targetNumber = data;
      this.displayCurrentNumber = data.level1.level2.target;
    }
  }
}
```

#### child-cmp.component.ts

```
export class ChildCmpComponent {
  private _targetNum: any;
  public displayNumberObj: any;
  public displayNumber: number;
  public changeArray: string[] = [];
  @Input() 
  set targetNumber(target: any){
    this.changeArray.push('Setter(),');
    this._targetNum = target;
    this.setDisplay(this._targetNum);
  }
  get targetNumber(): any{
    this.changeArray.push('Getter(),');
    return this._targetNum;
  }
  private setDisplay(target: any): void{
    this.changeArray.push('setDisplay(),');
    this.displayNumberObj = target;
    this.displayNumber = target.level1.level2.target;
  }
}
```

Comment: The setter is only called once because the object passed is always the same object. Its **state** changes, but that doesn't trigger an input change.

Comment: Why is it that I can see the value of the 'target' property updating in the child component hten? Is it, because the first time the setter was called the child components property displayNumberObj now holds a reference to the original object so it automatically updates without having to call the setter? @JBNizet

Comment: Yes. The template displays the state of the object, you change the state of the object, so the template displays the new state.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I failed to recognize that the value of a property in an object changing does not change the object, but rather the state of that object. So Object A is still Object A and Angulars change detection is unaware of the state change hence why @Input binding never fires the setter. It appears I still have much to learn, and you've given me a great starting place. Thank you very much for your response and time.

Comment: this behavior is further explained in the docs, kinda hard to find though, check the gif + explanation to it at https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges

Comment: That gif paints a clear picture as to how Angular reacts to state changes or more so, doesn't react to state change. Initially I didn't make the correlation between the OnChanges event and the @Input decorator both depending on change detection. I thought if onChanges didn't work then I could use a setter on the binding, but overlooked that the binding itself depends on that very same change detection. Thank you for pointing out that information in the docs, Jota.Toledo

Comment: @Narm If you understood the problem, and came up with a solution, I would suggest you to add it as answer and accept it. This is a valid question that could be useful for others.

Comment: Ok, yeah I'd be happy to write up an answer. I wasn't sure if I should, on account of you and JBNizet helping me understand the problem in the comments, but I will work on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Recognizing that the **@Input decorator is only updated during change detection**, therefore the setter assigned to the bound data will only fire during change detection. This fact is clearly stated in the first two comment lines in the Angular source code.

`export interface InputDecorator {
  /**
   * Declares a data-bound input property.
   *
   * Angular automatically updates data-bound properties during change detection.
   *`

2. From 1, it then follows that we need to **understand how Angulars change detection applies to non-primatives**.

To help explain this I will use the following object ObjA:

```
public ObjA = {
    'prop1': 'value1',
    'prop2': 'value2'
  }
```

**Angulars change detection fires when the value of the data bound property changes**. However, when the property being bound to is an object like `ObjA`, it is a reference of `ObjA` that gets bound to, not the object itself. It is for this reason when a property value in `ObjA` changes ( a state change)  Angulars change detection does not fire. **Angular is not aware of the state of `ObjA`, but rather the reference to `ObjA`.**

Thank you to @JBNizet and @Jota.Toledo for providing me the information (in the above comments) I needed to understand this topic.

Comment: In other words this isn't possible due to you answer, thanks for the clarification Narm!