# Angular input setter triggering only once

Tags: angular, typescript, setter, angular-decorator

I want to preface the question saying I have already read and understood other potentially duplicate questions (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955427/angular-input-getter-setter-and-non-primitive-values)) and have been unable to make this work leading me to believe that the problem is a little different in nature or I misunderstood something.

**The context:** I have a parent component with two child components (a side menu and a main view). The side menu has some filters in the form of checkboxes bound to an object via `[(ngModel)]` and trigger an event using `(ngModelChange)="changeFilter()"` within the template.

In the parent component I catch the event: `(filter)="updateFilters($event)"`. This function changes a public filter variable which I then pass along to the other child component like this: `[filterObject]="filters"`

In the main view component I feed the filterObject variable to a pipe in order to filter an array of objects.

**The problem:** The pipe gets called only once, after I changed the filter for the first time. The filterObject variable inside the main view shows up correctly updated when shown like this `{{filterObject | json}}` but the setter is never called. Console logs put in the setter and getter show that only the getter is getting access (2-4)

**Solutions I've tried:**

- Adding an additional parameter to the pipe to trigger it. The problem with this approach is that setting a new date needs to be done from the setter for `filterObject` which doesn't get called - as stated above
- Making the pipe impure (works but not a really good solution as it makes it process very big arrays of complex objects 2-4 times per click)
- Making the parent update the filter variable, not through an assignment operator, but through `Object.assign` in order to change the reference and potentially trigger the setter

**Solutions I'm considering:** If I don't manage to figure out what the problem is I'm thinking of making a service to communicate between the two components via observers. Otherwise I might have to settle for an impure pipe with some custom change detection embedded (I'm thinking of converting the filter object to a JSON string and checking the length).

**side-menu-component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="filter-type-2" name="filter-type-2" [(ngModel)]="filterObject.type.me" (ngModelChange)="changeFilter()">
```

**side-menu-component.ts**

```
 @Output() filter = new EventEmitter();
 public filterObject = {
    type: {
        mo: true,
        me: true,
        ar: true,
        cto: true,
        gl: true,
        dl: true
    },
    status: {
        unreviewed: true,
        approved: true,
        other: true
    }
};

// ...

changeFilter() {
    this.filter.emit(this.filterObject);
}
```

**parent-component.html**

```
<aside>
     <app-article-view-aside [article]="article" (close)="closeModal($event)" (filter)="updateFilters($event)"></app-article-view-aside>
</aside>
<div class="articleContainerMainView">
     <app-article-view-main [article]="article" [filterObject]="filters"></app-article-view-main>
</div>
```

**parent-component.ts**

```
updateFilters(newFilter) {
    this.filters = newFilter;
}
```

**main-view-component.html**

```
<app-finding
        *ngFor="let finding of findings | findingsFilter:filterDate:filterObject; let i = index"
        [finding]="finding"></app-finding>
```

**main-view-component.ts**

```
@Input() set filterObject(filterObject) {
    console.log('setter');
    this._filterObject = filterObject;
    this.filterDate = Date.now();
}

get filterObject() {
    console.log('getter');
    return this._filterObject;
}

private _filterObject = {};

public filterDate = Date.now();
```

**console output when first displaying the page:**

```
setter
getter
getter
getter
getter
```

I really want to do it "The Angular Way" so my question to you is what am I missing here?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It may be that your side menu component emits the same object. Its content may be altered, but the emitted object is still the same. Consider emitting a copy of the object instead. `Object.assign({}, this.filterObject)` may help you.

Comment: Wow, such a simple solution for such a complicated problem. I had tried using Object.assign but on the parent component not on the original component.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to the change detection of your lifecycle. Without a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I can't really tell you how to solve it, but i can definitely tell you how to work around it.

Start by giving you second component a template variable, and tell your output to update the data in it :

```
<aside>
     <app-article-view-aside [article]="article" (close)="closeModal($event)" (filter)="mainView.updateData($event)"></app-article-view-aside>
</aside>
<div class="articleContainerMainView">
     <app-article-view-main #mainView [article]="article" [filterObject]="filters"></app-article-view-main>
</div>
```

In your second component, instead of using a pipe, update your value in the function :

```
updateData(event) {
  // original data is the unfiltered array of data
  this.findings = this.originalData.filter(...);
}
```

And in your template it becomes

```
<app-finding
    *ngFor="let finding of findings; let i = index"
    [finding]="finding"></app-finding>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you pass the filter for the first time, you gave it the a reference. So, every time you change it, the change detection of angular will never detect it because you did not change the filter object or reference.

Solution: I guess you have two solutions:
1. Every time you update the filter change its reference by copy it.
2. Implement ngDoCheck in your pipe, if i am not wrong it will detect this change even if your reference still the same.